# spark scala filter array of strings column with list of strings very slow performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, user-defined-functions, broadcast

I have an `ArrayType[StringType]` column (`col1`).

I want to filter each array in the column using list of string of length ~100k strings so I create `col2` of `StringType`.

My current solution is very slow.
How can I speed it up?

```
val dict: Seq[String] // loaded from file and parsed

...

case class DictFilter(dict: Seq[String]) {
  def filterWithDictUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf(filterWithDict _)

  private val filters: Seq[String] = SparkContext.getOrCreate().broadcast(dict).value

  private def filterWithDict(words: Seq[String]): String = words.filter(filters.contains).mkString(" ")
}

...

df.withColumn("colFiltered", DictFilter(dict).filterWithDictUdf(col("col1")))
```

Comment: You can use Vector instead of Seq to see if it improves.